# XPath and lxml syntax

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a XML file with the structure as shown below:

```
<x>
   <y/>
   <y/>
   .
   .
</x>
```

The number of `<y>` tags are arbitrary.

I want to get the text of the `<y>` tags and for this I decided to use XPath. I have figured out the syntax, say for the first `y`: (Assume `root` as `x`)

`textFirst = root.xpath('y[1]/text()')`

This works as expected.

However my problem is that I won't be knowing the number of `<y>` tags beforehand, so to fix that, I did this:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for number in root.getiterator('y'):
...     count += 1
```

So now I know that there are `count` number of  `y` in `x`. (Is there a better way to get the number of tags? If yes, please suggest)

However, if I do this:

```
>>> def try_it(x):
...     return root.xpath('y[x]/text()')
... 
>>> try_it(1)
[]
```

It returns an empty list.

So my question is: not knowing the arbitrary number of tags, how do I get an XPath syntax or expression for it and using `lxml`?

Sorry if something is not clear, I tried my best to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about `'y[%i]/text()' % x` ?

now you see where you did a mistake? :)

( .. note that you can capture all y elements together with xpath `'y'` or `'//y'` )

Comment: Ohhhhhhh! It works! Thank you so much. Very stupid of me. 

Is my method of getting the number of `y` tags OK or is there a shorter version?

Comment: PulpFiction: it happens :) i have updated the answer with a hint on simpler way how to do it simpler

Comment: mykhal: Thanks for the help, you saved me lot of toil. Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of `y` nodes, you can use the XPath expression `'count(/x/y)'`.

Also, I think the problem with your expression in the `try_it` function is that you appear to be using the literal value `x` instead of concatenating the input parameter into the XPath expression.

Maybe something like this would work:

```
 >>> def try_it(x):
...     return root.xpath('y[' + x + ']/text()')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: count() was just what I needed. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Why does count() return float?

Comment: @PulpFiction - `lxml` returns float for any XPath expression that returns a numeric result (in Java, the corresponding result is a `Double`). You should just be able to downcast it.

Comment: Thanks, I can do that however I was just curious as to why it returns a float.